# Problemas en la generación de PDF en Linux

Tags: php, mpdf

En Windows, el reporte se genera sin problema, pero en Linux Debian se me presentan dos problemas:

1. La imagen de fondo se repite en todas las paginas cuando solo la defino para el primer HTML y para el resto coloco otra en blanco.
2. No muestra la imagen que coloco en la primera página.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

          $nombre=$_FILES['file']['name'];
          $destino =  "img/".$nombre;
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destino)) {
              $r="bine";
          }else{
            $r="no";
          }

$mpdf->useOddEven = 1;


$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/bootstrap.min.css');

if ($idioma=='ESP') {
    $proc='Proceso';
    $fe='Fecha';
}else{
    $proc='Process';
    $fe='Date';
}

$html1 = '
<body>
<div style="position: relative;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;" align="center">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <img class="bg" src="img/'.$nombre.'" alt="">
        <h1 style="position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;color:white" align="center">'.$_POST['nombre-cli'].'</h1>
        <h5 style="color:white" align="center">Auditor: '.$_POST['auditor'].'</h1>
        <h5 style="color:white" align="center">'.$proc.": ".$_POST['proceso'].'</h1>
        <h6 style="color:white" align="center">'.$fe.": ".$_POST['fecha'].'</h1>
    </div>
    </body>';
    $html='<body style="background:none">  
    <div class="col-md-12">';

        include_once 'funcion/bd_con.php';

        $sql="SELECT * FROM iso27001_planear";
        $sql=$conn->query($sql);

        if ($idioma=='ESP') {
          $titulo="Planear";
          $objetivoT= 'Pregunta';
          $cumpleT='Cumple Satisfactoriamente';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Cumple Parcialmente';
          $Cumplepa='CP';
          $noCumpleT='No Cumple';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observaciones';
          $noapli="No Aplica";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }else{
          $titulo="Plan";
          $objetivoT='Question';
          $cumpleT='Complies Satisfactorily';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Partially Compliant';
          $Cumplepa='PC';
          $noCumpleT='No Compliance';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observations';
          $noapli="Not Applicable";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }
        $html.= "<p class='text-center font-weight-bold lead'>$titulo</p>";
          $html.= '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">';
          $html.= '<tr>';
          $html.= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>Item</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$objetivoT.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$cumpleTa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$Cumplepa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$noCumpleTa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '</tr>';
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
          $fecha1=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
          $fecha2=date("s/m/i/m/d/Y");
          $temp= $fecha1."/".$row['id']."/".$fecha2;
          $tem="";
          for($i=0,$len=strlen($temp);$i<$len;$i++){
            if(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))==32 ){
              $tem=$tem." ";
            }else{
              $tem .= chr(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))+1);
            }
          }
          $html .= '<tr>';
          $html .= '<td class="text-center"><small>'.$row['item'].'</small></td>';
          $html .= "<td><small>".$row["pregunta_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          if($row['estado']==2){
            $marca2='X';
            $color2='style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"';
          }else{
            $marca2='';
            $color2="";
          }

          if($row['estado']==1){
            $marca1='X';                
            $color1='style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0)"';
          }else{
            $marca1='';
            $color1="";
          }

          if($row['estado']==0){
            $color0='style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)"';
            $marca0='X';
          }else{
            $marca0='';
            $color0="";
          }
          $html .= "<td $color2><small>".$marca2."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color1><small>".$marca1."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color0><small>".$marca0."</small></td>";


          $html.='</tr>';
          }
          $html.='</table>';
          if ($idioma=='ESP') {
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT</p>";
            $html.="<p>CP: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT</p>";
          }else{
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT</p>";
            $html.="<p>PC: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT</p>";
          }
          $html.='</div>
          <pagebreak/>';

        $html.='<div class="col-md-12">';

        include_once 'funcion/bd_con.php';

        $sql="SELECT * FROM iso27001_hacer";
        $sql=$conn->query($sql);

        if ($idioma=='ESP') {
          $titulo="Hacer";
          $objetivoT= 'Pregunta';
          $cumpleT='Cumple satisfactoriamente';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Cumple parcialmente';
          $Cumplepa='CP';
          $noCumpleT='No Cumple';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observaciones';
          $noapli="No aplica";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }else{
          $titulo="Do";
          $objetivoT='Question';
          $cumpleT='Complies satisfactorily';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Partially compliant';
          $Cumplepa='PC';
          $noCumpleT='No Compliance';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observations';
          $noapli="Not applicable";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }
        $html.= "<p class='text-center font-weight-bold lead'>$titulo</p>";
          $html.= '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">';
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
          $fecha1=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
          $fecha2=date("s/m/i/m/d/Y");
          $temp= $fecha1."/".$row['id']."/".$fecha2;
          $tem="";
          for($i=0,$len=strlen($temp);$i<$len;$i++){
            if(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))==32 ){
              $tem=$tem." ";
            }else{
              $tem .= chr(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))+1);
            }
          }
          if ($row['tipo']==0) {
            $html .= '<tr>';
          $html .= '<td class="text-center"><small>'.$row['item'].'</small></td>';
          $html .= "<td><small>".$row["pregunta1_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td><small>".$row["pregunta2_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          if($row['estado']==3){
            $color3='style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"';
            $marca3='X';
          }else{
            $marca3='';
            $color3='';
          }

          if($row['estado']==2){
            $color2='style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0)"';
            $marca2='X';
          }else{
            $marca2='';
            $color2='';
          }

          if($row['estado']==1){
            $color1='style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)"';
            $marca1='X';
          }else{
            $marca1='';
            $color1='';
          }

          if($row['estado']==0){
            $color0='style="background-color:rgb(180,198,231)"';
            $marca0='X';
          }else{
            $marca0='';
            $color0='';
          }
          $html .= "<td $color3><small>".$marca3."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color2><small>".$marca2."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color1><small>".$marca1."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color0><small>".$marca0."</small></td>";
          $html.='</tr>';
          }else{
           $html .= '<tr>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$row['item'].'</small></td>';
          $html .= "<td style='background-color:#b8daff'><small>".$row["pregunta1_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td style='background-color:#b8daff'><small>".$row["pregunta2_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          if ($row['item'] =='') {
            $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$cumpleTa.'</small></td>';
            $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$Cumplepa.'</small></td>';
            $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$noCumpleTa.'</small></td>';
            $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$noaplia.'</small></td>';
          }else{
            $html .= "<td style='background-color:#b8daff'><small></small></td>";
            $html .= "<td style='background-color:#b8daff'><small></small></td>";
            $html .= "<td style='background-color:#b8daff'><small></small></td>";
            $html .= "<td style='background-color:#b8daff'><small></small></td>";
          }

          $html.='</tr>';
          }
          }




          $html.='</table>';              
          $html.='</div>';
          $html.='<div>';

          if ($idioma=='ESP') {
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   NC: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>CP: $noCumpleT  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   NA: $noapli</p>";
          }else{
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; PC: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   NA: $noapli</p>";
            $html.="<p></p>";
          }
          $html.='</div><pagebreak/>';

          $sql="SELECT * FROM iso27001_verificar";
        $sql=$conn->query($sql);

        if ($idioma=='ESP') {
          $titulo="Verificar";
          $objetivoT= 'Pregunta';
          $cumpleT='Cumple Satisfactoriamente';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Cumple Parcialmente';
          $Cumplepa='CP';
          $noCumpleT='No Cumple';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observaciones';
          $noapli="No Aplica";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }else{
          $titulo="Verify";
          $objetivoT='Question';
          $cumpleT='Complies Satisfactorily';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Partially Compliant';
          $Cumplepa='PC';
          $noCumpleT='No Compliance';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observations';
          $noapli="Not Applicable";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }
        $html.= "<p class='text-center font-weight-bold lead'>$titulo</p>";
          $html.= '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">';
          $html.= '<tr>';
          $html.= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>Item</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$objetivoT.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$cumpleTa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$Cumplepa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$noCumpleTa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '</tr>';
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
          $fecha1=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
          $fecha2=date("s/m/i/m/d/Y");
          $temp= $fecha1."/".$row['id']."/".$fecha2;
          $tem="";
          for($i=0,$len=strlen($temp);$i<$len;$i++){
            if(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))==32 ){
              $tem=$tem." ";
            }else{
              $tem .= chr(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))+1);
            }
          }
          $html .= '<tr>';
          $html .= '<td class="text-center"><small>'.$row['item'].'</small></td>';
          $html .= "<td><small>".$row["pregunta_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          if($row['estado']==2){
            $marca2='X';
            $color2='style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"';
          }else{
            $marca2='';
            $color2="";
          }

          if($row['estado']==1){
            $marca1='X';                
            $color1='style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0)"';
          }else{
            $marca1='';
            $color1="";
          }

          if($row['estado']==0){
            $color0='style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)"';
            $marca0='X';
          }else{
            $marca0='';
            $color0="";
          }
          $html .= "<td $color2><small>".$marca2."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color1><small>".$marca1."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color0><small>".$marca0."</small></td>";


          $html.='</tr>';
          }
          $html.='</table>';
          if ($idioma=='ESP') {
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT</p>";
            $html.="<p>CP: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT</p>";
          }else{
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT</p>";
            $html.="<p>PC: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT</p>";
          }
          $html.='</div>
          <pagebreak/>';

          $sql="SELECT * FROM iso27001_actuar";
        $sql=$conn->query($sql);

        if ($idioma=='ESP') {
          $titulo="Actuar";
          $objetivoT= 'Pregunta';
          $cumpleT='Cumple Satisfactoriamente';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Cumple Parcialmente';
          $Cumplepa='CP';
          $noCumpleT='No Cumple';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observaciones';
          $noapli="No Aplica";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }else{
          $titulo="Act";
          $objetivoT='Question';
          $cumpleT='Complies Satisfactorily';
          $cumpleTa='CS';
          $Cumplep='Partially Compliant';
          $Cumplepa='PC';
          $noCumpleT='No Compliance';
          $noCumpleTa='NC';
          $observacionesT='Observations';
          $noapli="Not Applicable";
          $noaplia="NA";
        }
        $html.= "<p class='text-center font-weight-bold lead'>$titulo</p>";
          $html.= '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">';
          $html.= '<tr>';
          $html.= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>Item</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$objetivoT.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$cumpleTa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$Cumplepa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '<td style="background-color:#b8daff" class="text-center"><small>'.$noCumpleTa.'</small></td>';
          $html .= '</tr>';
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
          $fecha1=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
          $fecha2=date("s/m/i/m/d/Y");
          $temp= $fecha1."/".$row['id']."/".$fecha2;
          $tem="";
          for($i=0,$len=strlen($temp);$i<$len;$i++){
            if(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))==32 ){
              $tem=$tem." ";
            }else{
              $tem .= chr(ord(substr($temp,$i,1))+1);
            }
          }
          $html .= '<tr>';
          $html .= '<td class="text-center"><small>'.$row['item'].'</small></td>';
          $html .= "<td><small>".$row["pregunta_$idioma"]."</small></td>";
          if($row['estado']==2){
            $marca2='X';
            $color2='style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0)"';
          }else{
            $marca2='';
            $color2="";
          }

          if($row['estado']==1){
            $marca1='X';                
            $color1='style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0)"';
          }else{
            $marca1='';
            $color1="";
          }

          if($row['estado']==0){
            $color0='style="background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)"';
            $marca0='X';
          }else{
            $marca0='';
            $color0="";
          }
          $html .= "<td $color2><small>".$marca2."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color1><small>".$marca1."</small></td>";
          $html .= "<td $color0><small>".$marca0."</small></td>";


          $html.='</tr>';
          }
          $html.='</table>';
          if ($idioma=='ESP') {
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT</p>";
            $html.="<p>CP: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT</p>";
          }else{
            $html.="<p>CS: $cumpleT</p>";
            $html.="<p>PC: $Cumplep</p>";
            $html.="<p>NC: $noCumpleT</p>";
          }
          $html.='</div>';

   $html.'</body>';



    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
    $mpdf->AddPageByArray([
        'margin-left' => 0,
        'margin-right' => 0,
        'margin-top' => 0,
        'margin-bottom' => 0,
    ]);
    $mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', "url('img/background1.jpg')");
    $mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image-resize', 1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html1, 2);

    $mpdf->setHeader($_POST['proceso']. ' / '. $_POST['fecha']);

    $mpdf->AddPageByArray([
        'margin-left' => 10,
        'margin-right' => 9,
        'margin-top' => 16,
        'margin-bottom' => 13,
    ]);
    $mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background', "url('img/prueba.png')");
    $mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('background-image-resize', 1);
    $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 3);

    $mpdf->Output('report.pdf','D');
```

Comment: Cuando subes tus archivos a Linux siempre chequea los permisos probablemente está sobreescribiendo y no tiene permisos en la careta destino para generarlo bien

Comment: Ya le aplique permisos chown y 777 a la libreria mpdf y al archivo que genera el pdf